# Having trouble saving images to a public directory [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-camerax

So I hope the title makes sense but heres more context .

I want to make my own camera app and I am following this [Google Practice](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#5) for cameraX. I have got the camera working on my physical phone but the problem is I cant view my images that I have taken. Weird thing is the images appear in the gallery the next day and not right after taking a photo.

Now im not too sure why that is but after researching it seems that the file is not being saved in a public directory at least thats the conclusion I have succumbed to. This is the directory that the app saves to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.astro.openingcamera/openingCamera.

This is the block of code that produces the directory

```
    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
    val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
        File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
    return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
        mediaDir else filesDir
}
```

So is there a away to modify this block so that it allows me to view the images right after taking the photo ? cause keep in mind the images dont appear in the gallery right after taking the photo.

Others have pointed to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) but I dont really understand it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Android version runs on used device? Further you shouls start the mediascanner for your new file. Then it gets indexed and you see it in the gallery right away.

Comment: I think im using API 29 or 30. I havent heard of media scanner so ill look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as suggested by blackapps I used a mediascanner to update the directory so heres my code

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this ,
            arrayOf(outputDirectory.toString()),null,
    null)
```